# set the value from an input field on my html page in Localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

How can I set the value from an input field on my html page with localstorage.
Like if I type something in an input field for example "Hello" and I press on a button Submit. Then the title from the page should change to "Hello". But it needs to be saved in localstorage if possible.

```html
<p>Hello</p>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="text">Change title:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputBox" id="text" name="text">
</div>

<button>submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save value to localStorage with `localStorage.setItem` and `localStorage.getItem` to get localStorage value. Here is the working example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("inputvalue")){
      $('p').text(localStorage.getItem("inputvalue"));
    }
    
    $('button').on('click', function() {
    localStorage.setItem("inputvalue", $('#text').val());
    $('p').text(localStorage.getItem("inputvalue"));
});
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello</p>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="text">Change title:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputBox" id="text" name="text">
</div>

<button>submit</button>
```

Comment: This works almost. When I press f5 the text just changes back to Hello. I think it doesn't save it correctly Or I am doing something wrong

Comment: You need to check if `localStorage` has value on it or not on `onload` event. Code is updated @akin

Comment: Still have the same problem. It does save in localstorage but it doesn't show on my page after refreshing the page. it changes back to "hello" after every refresh

Comment: @akin did you receive any error? any way code is updated check it once.

Comment: Yes I did, and just to be sure I tried it in codepen with litterly copy-paste your code and here is the same issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yKRQjG It does change, but when you press f5 (or just refreshing page) the text go back to "hello"

Comment: In this answer I think you have an error.  You check if "popup" and if true then you get "inputValue" ...

Comment: @floverdevel exactly.

Comment: That did the thing! I was doubt about the "popupp" thing. But I thought maybe it is the way it should. Changing it to ("inputvalue") made it work! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need some Javascript for this.

You can take the value of the input like so :

`var inputValue = document.getElementById("text").value;`

Then you can set that into the localStorage.

`localStorage.setItem("text", inputValue );`

Then you can retrieve the value from local storage with

`var valueFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("text")`

Identify your submit button and your text area for your header :

`<button id="submit">submit</button>`

`<p id="heading-title">`

Then get the click event for that button and perform your DOM update.

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   document.getElementById("heading-title").innerHTML = valueFromStorage;
})
```

### References

[GetElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById%20getElementById)

[LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Okay but How can I set the item from localstorage?

Comment: @akin I have updated with the full information, but I suggest you do a bit of research first. There seems to be a lot of other basic information you are missing.